# Why is BeautifulSoup not extracting all of HTML from a webpage?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from this website: [searchgurbani](https://www.searchgurbani.com/guru_granth_sahib/ang_by_ang). This website has some old scripture translated in English and Punjabi (an Indian Language) line-by-line. It makes a very good parallel corpus. I have successfully extracted all the English translations in a separate text file. But when I go for Punjabi, It returns nothing.

This is the Inspect element screenshot: (Highlighted text is the translated Punjabi language)

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzai7.png)

In Screenshot 1, highlighted text which belongs to *class=lang_16* is not listed in the soup object *beautiful* which should contain all of the HTML. Here is the Python code:

```
outputFilePunjabi = open("1.txt","w",newline="",encoding="utf-16")
r=urlopen("")
beautiful = BeautifulSoup(r.read().decode('utf-8'),"html5lib")
#beautiful = BeautifulSoup(r.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
punjabi_text = beautiful.find_all(class_="lang_16")
for i in punjabi_text:
  outputFilePunjabi.write(i.get_text())
  outputFilePunjabi.write('\n')
```

If I run the same code with *class_=lang_4* it does the work.

Please do the following to see lang_16 in inspect element:

*Please do the following on that web page: Go to preferences --> Tick "translation of Sri Guru Granth Sahib ji (by S. Manmohan Singh) - Punjabi" under Additional Translations available on Guru Granth Shahib: --> scroll down - submit changes -> reopen page*

Please guide me where I am going wrong.

(python version = 3.5)

*PS: I have very less experience in web scraping.*

Comment: Interesting, I don't actually see the element with `class="lang_16"` on the page. Are you sure the link is correct?..

Comment: Please do the following on that web page: Go to preferences -> Tick "translation of Sri Guru Granth Sahib ji (by S. Manmohan Singh) - Punjabi" under Additional Translations available on Guru Granth Shahib: -> scroll down - submit changes -> reopen page | You should see it @alecxe

Comment: First of all, "Inspect" does not show the original HTML, but whatever results after various modifications of it. Use "View source" to see the actual source which you can expect to find in your script. Then see if there is still any difference. Anyway, I dont see the contents from the screenshot  in either of those views.

Comment: Thank you @zvone for your efforts. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember you've suggested to do the following:

> Please do the following on that web page: Go to preferences -> Tick
>   "ranslation of Sri Guru Granth Sahib ji (by S. Manmohan Singh) -
>   Punjabi" under Additional Translations available on Guru Granth
>   Shahib: -> scroll down - submit changes

Now, this is also required when you download the page in Python. In other words, use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and **set the `lang_16="yes"` cookie** to enable the Punjabi translation:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("https://www.searchgurbani.com/guru_granth_sahib/ang_by_ang", cookies={
        "lang_16": "yes"
    })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
    for item in soup.select(".lang_16"):
        print(item.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
ਵਾਹਿਗੁਰੂ ਕੇਵਲ ਇਕ ਹੈ। ਸੱਚਾ ਹੈ ਉਸ ਦਾ ਨਾਮ, ਰਚਨਹਾਰ ਉਸ ਦੀ ਵਿਅਕਤੀ ਅਤੇ ਅਮਰ ਉਸ ਦਾ ਸਰੂਪ। ਉਹ ਨਿਡਰ, ਕੀਨਾ-ਰਹਿਤ, ਅਜਨਮਾ ਤੇ ਸਵੈ-ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ਼ਵਾਨ ਹੈ। ਗੁਰਾਂ ਦੀ ਦਯਾ ਦੁਆਰਾ ਉਹ ਪਰਾਪਤ ਹੁੰਦਾ ਹੈ।
ਉਸ ਦਾ ਸਿਮਰਨ ਕਰ।
ਪਰਾਰੰਭ ਵਿੱਚ ਸੱਚਾ, ਯੁਗਾਂ ਦੇ ਸ਼ੁਰੂ ਵਿੱਚ ਸੱਚਾ,
ਅਤੇ ਸੱਚਾ ਉਹ ਹੁਣ ਭੀ ਹੈ, ਹੇ ਨਾਨਕ! ਨਿਸਚਿਤ ਹੀ, ਉਹ ਸੱਚਾ ਹੋਵੇਗਾ।
...
ਕਈ ਇਕ ਗਾਇਨ ਕਰਦੇ ਹਨ ਕਿ ਵਾਹਿਗੁਰੂ ਪ੍ਰਾਣ ਲੈ ਲੈਂਦਾ ਹੈ ਤੇ ਮੁੜ ਵਾਪਸ ਦੇ ਦਿੰਦਾ ਹੈ।
ਕਈ ਗਾਇਨ ਕਰਦੇ ਹਨ ਕਿ ਹਰੀ ਦੁਰੇਡੇ ਮਲੂਮ ਹੁੰਦਾ ਅਤੇ ਸੁੱਝਦਾ ਹੈ।
```

Comment: It works like charm! I was stuck here for last two weeks. Thank you so much. :) :)